# After rebooting server, service start without special chars

Tags: linux, mysql, java, character-encoding

I wrote a simple Java server. This service (java server) connects with a mySQL database. I am connecting to this service with a socket connection.

Everything works well when I start my service by command line.

```
service quiz start
```

I also added this service to autorun. [I use this simple wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux).

The problem occurs when service starts with autorun -- I don't have special characters. Every select from the database returns something like this "??" instead of "ąę".

When I restart the service everything is working well again.

```
service quiz stop 

service quiz start
```

Comment: Your program probably depends on the locale settings, and they are different when starting it interactively vs. through the startup script. You could set the correct value for `$LC_CTYPE` in the startup script and see if that helps.

Comment: Not related to you question, but I suggest looking into the `systemd` services. There are many tutorials, manuals etc. for example [here](https://github.com/logankp/systemd.net-tutorial). Systemd allows you to specify dependencies, so you can say that your service has to start after some others - for example, after the network is set up.